# How to run current line and advance in VS Code? (windows)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Let's say I have a few lines I want to run one-by-one.

```
x=5
y=6
print(x+y)
```

I set the cursor on `x=5` and press Shift + Enter, which according to the settings does this: **Python: Run current cell and advance**

However when I press shift + enter, it runs the current line, but doesn't advance it just stays there.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run current line and advance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59758754/how-to-run-current-line-and-advance)

Answer (score 2):

In order to "run cell and advance" as in a Jupyter Notebook, you need to first define the cells using the `#%%` command.
See here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py

```
#%%
x = 5

#%%
y = 6

#%%
print(x+y)
```

Your other option is to create an actual Jupyter Notebook with the .ipynb extension. VS Code will then automatically create the cells.

Comment: How can I do this without creating a new cell? I would like to run the code line by line without having to type `#%%` every time

Comment: Not currently possible

Answer (score 0):

I use the [vscode-jupyter-python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kylebarron.vscode-jupyter-python) extension to run and advance without using code cell syntax.