# How to run current line and advance?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Note: Windows 10

When I press `shift + enter`, it runs the current line, but doesn't advance. It just stays there.

When I press `ctrl + enter`, it advances to the next line, but doesn't run the code.

I want to do both of these at the same time.

Any idea how to set this up?

If I check the settings, `Shift + Enter` is currently "run current **cell** and advance", but I don't want to have to create cells every time I want to run one line. I was using Spyder previously, and it advances if you run the code line by line.

Please help, I'm going insane here. I have to manually press the down key every time I run a single line. This issue is also ungoogleable, I haven't found any information on how to do this, or if it is even possible.

Comment: Um, what exactly are you doing? Are you running a jupyter notebook inside vscode? Generally, in Python, you do not run code "line by line" (outside of a debugger).  Jupyter notebooks give you something like that, but they do it with cells, which are *like that but more flexible*.

Comment: Have you tried ctrl+shift+enter?  Sounds quite feasible in your situation

Comment: @HenryHarutyunyan that reverses the cursor ! I guess that's the joke

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sometimes I just want to do it. It's possible in Spyder. No I'm not running a jupyter notebook in vscode. What if I want to just run `x=5` once and then advance the line and then run `y=6` and then advance and run `print(x+y)`. All I want to know if that's possible.

Comment: @SCool what is a "cell" in this context, then? In any case, Spyder is an IDE that tries to emulate the RStudio environment. Python and R are two pretty different languages, generally, the basic tooling for each of them is going to be quite different. Python is a general-purpose programming language whereas R is a statistical programing environment. I'm not sure there is any built-in way to run Python code line-by-line in VSCode, but if there isn't there very well may be an extension out there that lets you do it. Or maybe use a Jupyter notebook, since it sounds like what you want.

Comment: OR you can use the debugger and manually step through your code, but it's not exactly going to work like it does in Spyder.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga that's exactly it, I'm used to R Studio's run line and advance. The "cell" in this context is whatever line the cursor is on. I use Jupyter notebooks a lot, but what I'm currently working on can't run in a notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recently switched to vscode and this has been bothering me as well. I will share here a workaround that works for me.

This solution is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61444964/10652754) answer.

**1. Install [macros](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ctf0.macros) extension**

**2. In settings.json**

```
"macros.list": {
    "execSelectiioninTerminaladvance": [
        "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText",
        "cursorDown",
        {"command": "$delay","args": {"delay": 100}},
        {"command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence","args": { "text": "\n" }},
    ],
}
```

**3. In keybinding.json:**

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+enter",
    "command": "macros.execSelectiioninTerminaladvance",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && jupyter.hascodecells"
},
```